# Emulate USB HID device on windows from a device connected to a remote linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, raspberry-pi, usb, hid

I want to be able to run a windows program and be able to see and access a remote HID device connected to my raspberry pi over the internet.

I was able to record/send packets over python on the raspberry pi itself. But i am looking to be able to run a windows program from the manufacturer that doesn't natively work on linux and access that HID device from a couple of rooms away (over wifi).

This is a interface for my solar converter, not a keyboard or mouse.

Basically

- Emulate a hid device on windows and two-way bridge all packets to the real HID device connected to a raspberry pi.

Hardware:

- Windows 10 laptop
- Raspberry pi 3 running raspbian
- Official adapter that turns the proprietary connector to a USB HID device

Comment: Suggestions on how to improve this question are welcome, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found usbip which seems to do what i want: https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win

It basically let's you use a remote usb device on linux as a local device.